# Google Sheets - Concatenate multiple cells in a row based on date/quantity and with line breaks

Tags: string, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I was hoping someone could assist with this. I'm looking for formulas for Column H and Column I - where it would (1) output the date and quantity respectively if there's only one instance of it, or (2) output the concatenate of dates and the concatenate of quantity with line breaks. I've been trying variations of FILTER, SEARCH, JOIN, REGEX, etc. but haven't found anything that works.

[image: Screenshot of example]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

H2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A10)&"", 
 TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(
 IF(A2:F10="",,COLUMN(A2:F10)&"♦"&ROW(A2:F10)&"♠♦"&TO_TEXT(A2:F10)&"×"), 
 MOD(COLUMN(A2:F10)-1, 2)=0)), "♦"), 
 "select max(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), "♠")), 
 "× |×$", CHAR(10))), 2, 0)))
```

I2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A10)&"", 
 TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(
 IF(A2:F10="",,COLUMN(A2:F10)&"♦"&ROW(A2:F10)&"♠♦"&TO_TEXT(A2:F10)&"×"), 
 MOD(COLUMN(A2:F10), 2)=0)), "♦"), 
 "select max(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), "♠")), 
 "× |×$", CHAR(10))), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! A few follow up questions: Can these formulas be adjusted to account for: 1) Additional orders (more columns added), 2) Shifting of columns (maybe it’s worth moving columns H/I to columns A/B to keep the formulas static), and 3) Have the formulas check against the text within the column headers “ETA” and “Quantity” (if that helps at all)?

Comment: @itsjesse yes you can add more columns just don't forget to adjust the ranges according. as of now MOD=2 skips every 2nd column and this action has no impact on performance